# What is the advantages or disadvantages using Total Variation norm instead of Wasserstein norm for measures' convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, mathematical-physics

So I am reading a paper on theoretical many particles physics, and I came across a part where they want to prove that the probability measures they constructed converge to each other in weak sense.

The norm that they use is total variation norm, i.e.,
$$ 
\|P\|_{Tv} = \int d|P|.
$$

Now before reading this paper, I always thought one way to see the convergence in measure if to use Wasserstein norm (or Monge-Kantorovich).

So what is the essential advantages/disadvantages in using TV-norm over Wasserstein?